# How to annotate types in the template?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```html
<template>
                  Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type. -->
  <v-table :ref="el => (table.ref = el)"></v-table>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      return {
        table: ref({
          ref: null,
        }),
      }
    },
  })
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: it is now [supported](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1439304854028029953).

---

Seems TypeScript support in the template is not available yet, quote from Vue's author Evan You:

> This is technically doable:
>
> 1. We use `@babel/parser` to parse inline expressions, which already comes with TypeScript support for free. I tested by adding `typescript` to the parser plugin list and your example compiles just fine.
> 2. We need to add a pass to strip type annotations, which can be done with `esbuild` so that will still be reasonably fast.
>
> Obviously this won't work for the in-browser build, but runtime and build-time compilations already have different levels of support.
>
> Still, I'll need to play with this and `@vuedx` to see whether the benefit justifies the extra cost.

Reference: [Support TypeScript in vue template](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1359#issuecomment-650241908)